# RxJS dispose resource when no subscribers, create when new subscribers

Tags: javascript, socket.io, rxjs

I want to create and keep a single socket while I have subscribers, disconnect when I no longer have subscribers and reconnect when subscribers return.

This is what I have so far but when a subscriber unsubscribes the socket is disconnected for everyone.

```
  constructor() {
    this.socket = io(this.URL)
  }

  public getValue(): Observable<string> {
    let observable = new Observable<string>(observer => {
      this.socket.on('value', (data) => {
        let v = data['value'];
        observer.next(v)
      })

      return () => {
        this.socket.disconnect()
      }
    })

    return observable
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't doing exactly what you want because you're creating a new Observable every time you call `getValue()`. For example when you call `getValue()` twice and subscribe to both of them you'll have two different Observables. Then if you unsubscribe from any of them you'll close the socket connection for every Observable that was using it.

So a better way is to keep the Observable as a separate variable chained with the `share()` operator that will keep always only one subscription to its source Observable and will unsubscribe from it when all observers unsubscribe.

```
private socket$: Observable<string> = new Observable<string>(
  observer => {
    this.socket.on('value', (data) => {
      let v = data['value'];
      observer.next(v);
    });

    return () => this.socket.disconnect();
  })
  .share();

public getValue(): Observable<string> {
  return this.socket$;
}
```

Comment: That seems a lot easier than what I'm trying right now :) Some of the subscribers use throttleTime, things have started acting a bit funny with the shared observable. Does this mean I have to create new Observables for each?

Comment: I don't know your app so I don't know what it should or shouldn't do or where you're using `throttleTime`.

Comment: basically some subscribers do this: `getValue().throttleTime(1000)...` or `getValue().delay(3000)...someThing()...delay(3000)...someThing()`. Now it acts like `.delay(3000)....delay(3000)...someThing()...someThing()`. In other words the delays are getting bundled at the start and all the other actions happen at once. It's very odd behaviour

Comment: I tried creating a new Observable (which was subscribed to socket and called `next` each time a new value was received) for each call to `getValue()` and the same issue occurs... but it doesn't with my original implementation.

Comment: Ok, this is very odd behavior that is probably out of scope for this question. But things are actually perfectly fine with this RxJS... After swapping to this implementation Angular has decided to not update it's data bindings on time. I don't even know how that is possible